# How get a current line in file opened with fopen?

Tags: php

I need to get a line position of file pointer from file like below.

```
string1\n
string2\n
string3\n
```

I'm reading file using this func.

```
function get() {
    $fp = fopen('example.txt', 'r');
    if (!$fp) {
        echo 'Error' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    while(!feof($fp)) {
        $string = trim(fgets($fp));
        if(!$string) {
                continue;
        } else {
            /*
            * Here I want to get a line number in this file
            */
            echo $string . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how about add a line counter for each fgets?

Comment: File will be read using fseek()

Comment: I'm confused; are you using `fgets()` to read the file or `fseek()`?  If you are using `fseek()` could you edit your question to reflect the code that you are actually using?

Comment: @NiLL but your example uses `fgets()` which fetches an entire line. Arsane's suggestion is still valid. Where do you use `fseek()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to use a counter.

```
function get() {

   // Line number counter
   $lncount = 0;

   $fp = fopen('example.txt', 'r');
   if (!$fp) {
       echo 'Error' . PHP_EOL;
   }
   while(!feof($fp)) {
      $string = trim(fgets($fp));

      // Increment line counter
      $lncount++;

      if(!$string) {
         continue;
      } else {

         // Show line
         echo "Current line: " . $lncount;

         echo $string . PHP_EOL;
      }
   }
}
```